# Have python translate the correct file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, filenames

I'm trying to make a small simple program that can make a video out of a bunch of pictures.

I found this:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -r 1 -i img%01d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4")
```

It works but only if the file names are imgxxx.png

my files are named: xx.xx.xx.xxx.jpg (example: 11.58.30.445.jpg). As you might understand the file names are made from the time the picture is taken.

I have tried several options but I can't make python read the correct files. I could rename all the files but I want the program to run by itself so renaming all the files is not the solution I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Have you tried `%02d.%02d.%02d.%03d.jpg`?

Comment: how are filenames supposed to be sorted ? a simple numeric sort is enough ? or please elaborate on the file naming convention

Comment: This does not seem a Python question to me. It is about how `ffmpeg`'s command line arguments are parsed. Python does *nothing* with this `os.system` string.

Comment: @CoryKramer %02d.%02d.%02d.%03d.jpg was the first thing I tried. I assumed it had to be something like that but that didn't work.

Comment: @Guillaume, other files are 11.58.31.387.jpg, 11.58.33.913.jpg, 11.58.35.226.jpg, etc. So it's just a time stamp per picture.

Comment: @usr2564301, I'm using python code, that's why I used the python tags.

Comment: That is not relevant. Underneath Python, you may be using Linux, Windows, or Mac OS X; not relevant either. All that Python's `os.system` command does is forward your exact string to the underlying OS, as a regular command-with-arguments line. Therefore, your question is "how to do this **with ffmpeg** arguments". It would be different if you would *use* Python to construct the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as @CoryKramer said in his comment. The easiest way is to find an order in which you want to sort your files before passing them to the os.system method. You can rename your files using a simple bash script or python script for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the glob pattern in the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

- `-pattern_type glob` may not be supported on Windows builds.
- Use `-framerate` instead of `-r` for image file demuxer.
- I added an output `-r` because many players cannot handle a frame rate of 1. Frames will be duplicated to go from a frame rate of 1 to 25.
- I added `-pix_fmt yuv420p` which is not needed for `mpeg4`, but recommended if you want to use `libx264` for a more compatible pixel format.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!  os.system("ffmpeg -r 2 -i %*.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4")
That's all it took.

Comment: @DutchNinja Your command is missing `-pattern_type glob` and is therefore using the deprecated `-pattern_type glob_sequence` instead. Use: `ffmpeg -y -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vcodec mpeg4 movie.mp4`